# Parameterized pipeline job to start parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying the below code for my parameterized pipeline job. i want to start job names taken from parameter to run parallel. 
And those jobs also parameterized jobs. how to start parameterized pipeline job to trigger parallel builds. I also tried by using list , but it didnt work. can anyone suggest me where am i going wrong

```
def stepsForParallel = [:]
node {
     JOBS=JOB_NAMES.split(',');
     for (job in JOBS) {
         def stepName = "running_${job}"
         stepsForParallel[stepName] = { ->  build job: "runnning_$job", parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH',value: $BRANCH),string(name: 'CHANGE_NUMBER',value: $CHANGE_NUMBER)] }
     } 

parallel stepsForParallel
```

}

I got output like :

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [running_a] { (Branch: running_a)
[Pipeline] [running_b] { (Branch: running_b)
[Pipeline] [running_a] }
[running_a] Failed in branch running_a
[Pipeline] [running_b }
[running_b] Failed in branch running_b
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

an exception which occurred:

in field itr
in field target
in field continue_
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field capture
in field def
in field locals
in field capture
in field def
in field closures
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5e5624f3
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.AbstractList$Itr
at      org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
```

how to start parameterized pipeline job to trigger parallel builds. I also tried by using list , but it didnt work. can anyone suggest me where am i going wrong

Comment: Try to remove `node {}` around `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to [JENKINS-34645](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34645)  .
Try to remove `node {}` around `for` loop and move iteration into `@NonCPS` function. Something like this

```
@NonCPS
def stepsForParallel(def jobsName) {
    def steps = [:]
    jobs = jobsName.split(',')
    for (job in jobs) {
        def stepName = "running_${job}"
        steps[stepName] = { ->
            build job: "runnning_$job", parameters: [string(name: 'BRANCH', value: BRANCH), string(name: 'CHANGE_NUMBER', value: CHANGE_NUMBER)]
        }
    }
    return steps
}

parallel stepsForParallel(JOB_NAMES)
```

Comment: this is working, but not as expected! doesnot return status of parallel jobs even if job is completed

Comment: @no1 I don't see in your answer that you expected to get result statuses of invoked builds. It would require a different approach.

Comment: no i mean, after completion, job should exit, but it freezes!

Comment: What if I want to use 2 split functions and JOB_NAMES is a parameter(check box) is there any better method, its not working